# Clisp reading list from file and flatten it, but not working, doesnt recognize lst as a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp

```
(defun read-file-list (infile)
  (with-open-file (instream infile :direction :input :if-does-not-exist nil)
   (when instream 
     (let ((list (make-list (file-length instream))))
       (read-sequence list instream)
       list))))


(setq lst (read-file-list "/home/Desktop/nested_list.txt"))

(flatten-list lst )

(print lst)

;(1 2 3 (4 5 (12 11 9 6) 4 8 (77 53(47)) (12 15 18)) 
; file has got this line
```

Comment: Note that `file-length` probably does not tell you what you want to know to read a file, if you are reading it as characters, because, at least on Unixoid systems, the only way to know the length of such a file *in characters*, rather than in bytes, is to read the whole file.

Comment: you would need to describe in a clear why what the actual problem is. FLATTEN-LIST for example seems to be unrelated to your problem.

Comment: @RainerJoswig main idea is flatten, i have error in flattening but my file is not list type, i need to convert it into list type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`READ-SEQUENCE`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rd_seq.htm) reads characters from a file. When you compute the `file-length` and call `read-sequence`, all you are doing is reading all characters in a flat list. Namely, `lst` in your example is this list:

```
(#\( #\1 #\  #\2 #\  #\3 #\  #\( #\4 #\  #\5 #\  #\( #\1 #\2 #\  #\1 #\1 #\
 #\9 #\  #\6 #\) #\  #\4 #\  #\8 #\  #\( #\7 #\7 #\  #\5 #\3 #\( #\4 #\7 #\)
 #\) #\  #\( #\1 #\2 #\  #\1 #\5 #\  #\1 #\8 #\) #\) #\Newline)
```

You can see that all elements in this list are characters, they are denoted with the `#\...` syntax. For example, the first item is described as follow (tested with SBCL, actual output may vary in your implementation):

```
* (describe (first lst))
#\(
[standard-char]

Char-code: 40
Char-name: LEFT_PARENTHESIS
; No value
```

(with-open-file (stream "/tmp/file-list.txt")
(read (make-concatenated-stream (make-string-input-stream "(")
stream
(make-string-input-stream ")"))))
**What you want to do is to call [`READ`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rd_rd.htm) on that file**:

```
* (with-open-file (in "/tmp/file-list.txt")
    (read in))
; Evaluation aborted on #<END-OF-FILE {1013420B23}>.
```

And it appears also your input file misses a closing parenthesis. After fixing that, you have:

```
* (with-open-file (in "/tmp/file-list.txt")
    (read in))
(1 2 3 (4 5 (12 11 9 6) 4 8 (77 53 (47)) (12 15 18)))
```

Here the read value is a list of numbers and nested lists.

```
* (describe (first *))
1
[fixnum]
; No value
```

---- Edit

Your `flatten-list` function seems to work, what I am saying is that your input list is in another file, and that you need to extract the data using the standard Lisp reader by calling `read`:

```
* (with-open-file (in "/tmp/file-list.txt")
    (flatten-list (read in)))

(1 2 3 4 5 12 11 9 6 4 8 77 53 47 12 15 18)
```

--- Edit 2

If your file contains the list elements, like this:

```
1 2 3 (4 5 (12 11 9 6) 4 8 (77 53(47)) (12 15 18))
```

Then you could write a loop, as follows:

```
(loop 
  for form = (read in nil in)
  until (eq form in)
  collect form)
```

Or, you could use a concatenated stream:

```
USER> (with-input-from-string (open "(")
        (with-input-from-string (close ")")
          (with-open-file (file "/tmp/file-list.txt")
            (read (make-concatenated-stream open file close)))))
(1 2 3 (4 5 (12 11 9 6) 4 8 (77 53 (47)) (12 15 18)))
```

Or equivalently:

```
(with-open-file (stream "/tmp/file-list.txt")
  (read (make-concatenated-stream (make-string-input-stream "(")
                                  stream
                                  (make-string-input-stream ")"))))
```

Comment: What is your suggestion, i did not understant, flatten func works for manuel input , but with lst is not work for

Comment: yes, your `lst` is a list of characters, "#\0" is a character, the kind of values you find in strings like `"0123"`, and this is different from the number 0. You are reading characters from the input file, so you have a big list of characters, including characters like "#\(" the open parenthesis; what you need to do is to parse the file as lisp data, so that a string `"(0 1 (2))"` is actually read as the list `(0 1 (2))` and not the sequence of characters `(#\0 #\1 #\( #\2 #\) #\))` (notice that this is a flat list).

Comment: oky, that worked,thx for it, but if my file dont start with  ' ( ' bracket   , it give error , 1 is not list

Comment: @Srknsmsk If your file doesn't contain the syntax of a Lisp list, but rather individual items, then you have to read them in a loop and accumulate them into a list.

Comment: i did it with string, but string contains other chars, i used getfromstring funct for this

Comment: @Srknsmsk I do not understand your comment, sorry (and getfromstring is not from Lisp so this is confusing); please give more context, more information about the problem you are having because I am trying to guess, but it is hard.

Comment: Srry for confuse, read-from-string i used, i wrote wrong,  i wrote this comment for @Kaz

Comment: There is just one problem, my file need to have two parenthesis ( ), one for start one for end, if i do that i can use (read in), it works with list type , but my file is not list type

Comment: Please edit your question and write what exactly is in your file, it will be more clear. For example if the file is "10 20 (30 (20 50)) 5 10" then you need to do write a loop as Kaz said.